# Wordpress - dynamic_sidebar - causes Error loading XML

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I recently took over wordpress code.
After updating wordpress to 5.2.2, it appears

```
Error loading XML
```

And then further debugging I found out is the sidebar-widget-home that causes it.

How can I find out where is this sidebar-widget-home defined ? sidebar-widget-post & sidebar-widget seems working fine

```
<div id="sidebar-wrap" class="left relative">
    <?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget-home' ) ) { ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget-home' ); ?> <-- problem
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else if ( is_single() || is_page() ) { ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget-post' ) ) { ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget-post' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget' ) ) { ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div><!--sidebar-wrap-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in Apperance->widgets for checking sidebar-widget-home?

Comment: I fixed it in that place. It doesnt say sidebar-widget-home though. it shows - "Home Sidebar Widget Right Area". Im curious still where is this defined "sidebar-widget-home"?

Comment: check definition in functions.php